# host_permissions and webRequest.onAuthRequired

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

### Preamble

Support for `blocking` in `webRequest.onAuthRequired` was added via `webRequestAuthProvider` in Chrome 108.

- [Issue 1135492: How to use proxy + onAuthRequired in manifest V3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135492)
- [web_request_api.cc](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_api.cc;l=2857)

`webRequest.onAuthRequired` registers and fires normally in Chrome 108 MV3 with the permission `"*://*/*"` but does not fire with permission `"*://*.domain.com/*"`.

The question is why does `webRequest.onAuthRequired` does not fire with `"*://*.domain.com/*"`?

### Details

All operations relate to the same proxy domain e.g. `*.domain.com`.

browser -> proxy (abc.domain.com) -> website

#### Using minimal `"*://*.domain.com/*"`  'host_permissions'

`webRequest.onAuthRequired` does not fire.

**Chrome MV3 manifest.json**

```json
"permissions": [
    "proxy",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestAuthProvider"
],

"host_permissions": [
  "*://*.domain.com/*"
],
```

**background.js**

```js
const urls = ['*://*.domain.com/*'];
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(this.process, {urls}, ['blocking']);
```

#### Using general `"*://*/*"`  'host_permissions'

`webRequest.onAuthRequired` fires normally.

**Chrome MV3 manifest.json**

```json
"host_permissions": [
  "*://*/*"
],
```

**background.js**

```js
const urls = ['*://*/*'];
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(this.process, {urls}, ['blocking']);
```

Comment: Normal MV3 extensions [can't use `blocking` in webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration-checklist/#api-blocking).

Comment: @wOxxOm Please note `webRequestAuthProvider` which was added & working in Chrome 108. Please also note that `"*://*/*"` works fine. The issue is not the lack of support for `blocking`. The issue is about the permission.

Comment: Listeners with `blocking` simply won't be registered. Remove it.

Comment: @wOxxOm As mentioned, the extension is working fine and the listener registers & fires normally with `"*://*/*"` in Chrome 108 MV3. That is not the question. The question is why it works with `"*://*/*"` and not with `"*://*.domain.com/*"`.

Comment: Assuming that removing `blocking` doesn't make it work, the only other reason is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm Please check https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_api.cc;drc=8a2e00a52d6ace899769663c1d5f5961d3b82be2;l=2878 and line 2886

Comment: @wOxxOm I am guessing that Chrome permission would regard both proxy & the target site. Therefore a permission for the proxy domain only, is not enough for it. In Firefox `webRequest.onAuthRequired` fires with the permission for the proxy domain only.

Comment: Not sure how I can help. If it works after adding host permissions for the proxy then it's a bug in the documentation, which doesn't mention the requirement, otherwise it's a bug in Chrome. Either way it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `["<all_urls>"]`.

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    this.process,
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['blocking']
);
```